# How to parse JSON with ruby classes in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

First of all I push in my database in a field a Ruby object converted to JSON.
This object is (for the example) something like this :

```
{ #<Project id: 16 ...> => {#<Task id: 122 ...> => {details: {:a => 180, :b => 220}, sub: {...}}}}
```

And so on... This is just to show you that I have a nested hash with some objects in it.

This hash is pushed into my database in JSON with the following instruction `Model.create(field: my_hash.to_json, ...)`. The field of the DB receiving this JSON Hash is a string.

Now when I want to retreive all of this data I just do this :

```
JSON.parse(Model.find(id)[:field])
```

But this gives me the keys that were object in strings. `#<Project id: 16...>` becomes `"#<Project:0x000...>"` and it's a string.

With this It's now impossible for me to do things such as `var.keys.first[:id] #which in my example should be 16` since the key has became a string and is no longer a Ruby object.

Is it possible to retrieve my data the way it was pushed ?

Comment: How you serialize your data into json?

Comment: With this instruction : `Model.create(field: my_hash.to_json, ...)`. I also edited my post :)

Comment: Well, that's not a valid json. In json, the keys must be strings, nothing else. So it is on you to serialize things properly and then deserialize it. For projects, for example, you could have the key as "projects/16". At parse time you would understand this structure and issue a `Project.find(16)`. Or something like that.

Comment: If it is just for storing stuff in the database, you could use YAML instead of JSON. Yaml supports serialization of complex types. Not as keys, though.

Comment: Alright, I'll look it up for YAML since it's not just for storing bur to be able to retreive it somewhere else later.. If it doesn't do the trick, I'll serialize in a way similar of your first comment. Thanks a lot ! ;)

Comment: May I know which db you are working on?

Comment: Why do want to store that `Project` instance (that probably is already stored in the database) in an serialized field in another object? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I first started with the storage of `Project` because i needed to acces it's attribute (since it's a rails record) both in my controller and my views and wanted to limit the SQL request I was doing, that's why I stored the instance instead of its id.
The problem I'm facing right now makes me beleive that it was the wrong solution :/